Calculating value of vanilla swap after effective date
I'm trying to find the value of a fixed to float interest rate swap using Rateslib library but I'm running into a few issues.
I've followed the code exactly as the link here  but now I'm trying to find the market value of the swap after initiation. For example, in the link, the swap becomes effective on 2023-11-21 but how would I calculate the value say on 2024-01-10? So far, some of the posts I've found say to make the new valuation date as the effective date but the valuation isn't matching with the correct answer due to the cashflow issues (and coupons). A similar question was asked in Quantlib  but I don't know what options are available in rateslib for this.
Also, would upfront premiums make a difference in the valuation initially? After initiation? If I make the new valuation date as the effective date, should I keep that argument in the IRS part of the code? Is there even an option to include the premium? I couldn't find anything similar to it in the documentation.
Appreciate any help!

Are you trying to find the net present value of an historic swap? Or are you trying to find some future value of a spot swap? (sure it may be a combination of those two but the essence of the question forms two categories). Helpful to know the context and the objective.

Thanks for the response. I'm trying to find the NPV of an old swap. Softwares like Bloomberg and Refinitiv provide the NPV but the code isn't matching up to it due to the cashflow issues.

See the new page: https://rateslib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/z_historical_swap.html

This is extremely helpful! Thank you!!
